# create private channel auth flow in php for pusher

Tags: php, pusher, pusher-js

I want to implement a private messaging chat using [pusher](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/encrypted-channels) PHP/JS API.
I need some help to setup a private channel and an auth endpoint with php, it's not clear from the docs if there is a default way to manage the users authentication for private channel. I've googled a bit and I've found some examples but I'm not using laravel so I can't apply them. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

### JS

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

          var pusher = new Pusher('12xxxxxx', {
            cluster: 'us',
            forceTLS: true
          });

          var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-encrypted-test-channel');
          channel.bind('message-event', function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          });

          channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
            console.log(members);
            console.log('successfully subscribed!');
          });
```

### PHP

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$options = array(
  'cluster' => 'eu',
  'useTLS' => true
);
$pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
  '12xxxxx',
  '2xxxxxx',
  '8xxxxxx',
  $options
);

$data['message'] = 'hello world';
$pusher->trigger('private-encrypted-test-channel', 'message-event', $data);
```

What's the correct way to auth the users in php and later in js for pusher API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create another PHP file (e.g. pusher_auth.php) to perform the authentication.  Use this code as a starting point (adapted from your code and Pusher's WordPress documentation, since WordPress under the hood is just layers of PHP):

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$options = array(
  'cluster' => 'eu',
  'useTLS' => true
);

$pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
  '12xxxxx',
  '2xxxxxx',
  '8xxxxxx',
  $options
);

// You need to define this function for your application, but for testing purposes, it always returns true

function user_is_authenticated(){
    // Insert your logic here
    return true;
}

if ( user_is_authenticated() )
{
  echo $pusher->socket_auth($_POST['channel_name'], $_POST['socket_id']);
}
else
{
  header('', true, 403);
  echo "Forbidden";
}
```

Now modify your JS code like this to add an authEndpoint parameter (change the name and relative path to match your PHP authentication file)

```
var pusher = new Pusher('12xxxxxx', {
    cluster: 'us',
    authEndpoint: '/pusher_auth.php',
    forceTLS: true
});
```